# How to check whether my network is scale free or not in R(igraph)

Tags: r, networking, igraph, sna

I made two-mode network to analyze if it's scale free or not.

I used igraph package in R. I made two-mode to one-mode network by cross-product. And I made igraph for each period data. It is an undirected network. I know how to make scale-free network but I can't see my graph is scale-free.

My code is

```
# Load and Make 1-mode matrix
function_1mode <- function(x) {
 p_csv <- read.csv(x, header=T)
 p_csv <- p_csv %>% select(-X)

 A <- as.matrix(p_csv)
 R <- t(A)%*%A
 diag(R) <- 0
 return(R)
}

# Make 2-mode matrix
Mode_1 = function_1mode(x = "P1_IPC.csv")
Mode_2 = function_1mode(x = "P2_IPC.csv")
Mode_3 = function_1mode(x = "P3_IPC.csv")

# Make a graph for each matrix
g1 = graph.adjacency(Mode_1, mode='undirected', weighted = TRUE, diag=FALSE)
g2 = graph.adjacency(Mode_2, mode='undirected', weighted = TRUE, diag=FALSE)
g3 = graph.adjacency(Mode_3, mode='undirected', weighted = TRUE, diag=FALSE)

# Vertex and Edge info
v_count3 <- vcount(g3)
e_count3 <- ecount(g3)
e_weight3 <- get.data.frame(g3)

# Degree Centrality
deg_g3 <- degree(g3)
D3 <- as.matrix(deg_g3)

# Betweeness Centrality
btw3 <- betweenness(g3)
B3 <- as.matrix(btw3)

# Evcent Centrality
evc3 <- evcent(g3)$vector
E3 <- as.matrix(evc3)

# Centralization
ctrl3 <- centralization.degree(g3)$centralization

# Density
dnsty3 <- edge_density(g3, loops=TRUE) 

# Components
cmp3_no <- components(g3)$no
cmp3_size <- components(g3)$csize
```

I wanna see if my network 'g3' is scale-free or not by using code in R.

Comment: What a scale-free graph is?